# How to combine function with input and except

Tags: python, function, exception, return

I am trying to make Function that has input inside function.

My issue is that if I put the input inside the function the program wants values my_function(??,??) and after that it also asks same values for input.

If I move input to main program how can I deal the Except value error?

```
def my_function(value1, value2)
try:
    value1 = float(input("enter float value 1: "))
    value2 = float(input("enter float value 2: "))

except ValueError:
    print("not a float value")

else:
    result = value2 + value2
    return result
```

Comment: If the input is inside the function then don't ask for it as input parameters?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can either have the `input` inside the function, in which case the parameters aren't required :

```py
def my_function()
    try:
        value1 = float(input("enter float value 1: "))
        value2 = float(input("enter float value 2: "))
    except ValueError:
        print("not a float value")
    else:
        result = value2 + value2
        return result 

result = my_function()
if result is not None:
    #do something with the result
```

Or outside the function

```py
def my_function(value1, value2):
    result = value2 + value2
    return result 

try:
    value1 = float(input("enter float value 1: "))
    value2 = float(input("enter float value 2: "))
    result = my_function(value1, value2)
    #do something with the result
except ValueError:
    print("not a float value")
```

Answer (score 1):

You can set default value for your function with `def my_function(value1 = None, value2 = None)` then in your function, check if these values are set, else ask them with `input`